# syntax highlighting and auto-completion for CSS?

Tags: completion, syntax-highlighting, web-mode, css

How can I set up `css-mode` for syntax highlighting and autocompletion?  I installed `web-mode`, but it doesn't seem to be giving me any of those features.

Comment: The [`web-mode.el` page](http://web-mode.org/) states that it does both syntax highlighting and auto-completion.  It also gives instructions for how to set up the latter.

Comment: ok thanks. so i can get the same features by just implementing a .css instead of it having to be a .html as long as im in web mode , right?

Comment: css-mode already does syntax highlighting out of the box. Not to mention you're asking two very different questions here. **Please edit it to only ask about completion.** You can then ask a separate question if you're having problems with syntax highlighting.